# Create line between sharepoint list items

Tags: 2013, custom-list

I have a list that I would like to create lines in between a few items in order to separate descriptions from the next field and make them more easy to read. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: It's sharepoint 2013

Comment: Do you want to display the lines in the NewForm.aspx?

Comment: Just in between columns in the list view so that the descriptions are distinguishable from each other. Either that or group them with headings so I can get rid of the Descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$('tr.ms-itmhover td').css('border-bottom','1px solid black');
```

Using CSS:

```
tr.ms-itmhover td{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black
}
```